# Is it possible to parse nested json in sumologic?

Tags: logging, sumologic

So I have a log in this format:

```
{
    "date":1598808279.785381,
    "log":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"ts\":15988.7852,\"caller\":\"server/middlewares.go:26\",\"msg\":\"Request Log\",\"status\":200,\"method\":\"GET\",\"url\":\"/health\",\"duration\":0.000008323}",
    "container_id":"someid",
    "container_name":"/service-name",
    "source":"stdout"
}
```

I would like to extract out the status within the `log` field. After reading the docs it looks like I should be able to do:

```
_collector="MyService" | json auto | fields log.status
```

However, that throws a syntax error for `.`

Another solution I thought is that based upon how other languages work, piping usually returns the object so if I could incrementally return fields this should work:

```
_collector="MyService" | json auto | fields (log) | fields (status)
```

But that also doesn't work.

I've tried specifying a given field this this:

```
_collector="MyService" | json auto "fields.log.status"
```

But that doesn't work.

I've also tried directly pulling that value using field like this:

```
_collector="MyService" | json field=Message "log.status"
```

Finally, I tried doing all of these variations:

```
_collector="MyService" | json auto field=log "status"

_collector="MyService" | json auto field=log | fields status

_collector="MyService" | json auto field=log "status"

_collector="MyService" | json auto field=log "log.status"
```

But to no avail.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is the other way you found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

logs is escaped json as string, so you will need to json parse twice.

```
| json "log"
| json auto field=log
| fields status
```

Comment: I found another way but this works and is more clear. Thanks!